# Fans always on on HP laptop

Tags: debian, intel, fan

I recently installed Debian 9 on my HP-15bsxx laptop (after installing ElementaryOS 5.0 and **NOT** having this problem), and I have this issue where the fans are **always on** (not at full speed), even though:

- The CPU is not usually working on any intensive task. I'm running firefox, htop and  evince on the screenshot, on a i3+polybar setup.
  [image]
- The CPU's temp are usually between 30-45C.
  [image]
- The laptop is clean inside.
- I've run fwts and loaded the coretemp module (its the only recommended module).
- I have TLP installed and running.
- I have all the intel-microcode, firmware-misc-* and firmware-linux-* packages installed (free and non free)

[These](https://support.hp.com/ie-en/document/c05666797) are the laptop specs, the kernel is 4.19.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (its not a 4.19 problem as I had this issues with older kernels too), [this](https://pastebin.com/3YWwpHHa) is the result of lspci and [these](https://pastebin.com/szrGtn5d) are the results of dmesg in case you need it.

I know that this is a common issue, and Google has a lot of answers, but I've try them all and none worked for me.

Comment: Please click [edit] and list what you have tried, so we know not to suggest them. 'Everything' is rather vague. Please do not click [Add Comment] to reply instead of [edit] because older comments get pushed off the page when new comments arrive.